# Как присвоить maskedTextBox значение?

Tags: ооп, winforms, c++-cli

```
maskedTextBox7->Text = maskedTextBox1->Text;
```

maskedTextBox7 не принимает значение maskedTextBox1 сразу после ввода данных. Принимает только после ввода 4 значений в maskedTextBox1. Мне нужно чтобы maskedTextBox7 принимал сразу значения из maskedTextBox1. То есть ввел в 1-ое поле цифру 7 и в 7-ом поле появилась сразу эта цифра 7 и т.д. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Честно говоря, ничего не понятно. Уточните, пожалуйста, порядок действий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак вам нужно по вводу одного символа в первый текстбокс ввести тот же символ во второй текстбокс. Попробуйте отлавливать событие нажатия в первом текстбоксе и по нему вводить данные во второй:

```
private void mtb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    tbY.text = tbX.text
}
```

Код на C#, на C++ CLI должно быть похоже.